# How to use randomatic npm library in an Ionic app? I want to generate a random 6 digit number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I want to generate random 6 digit number so that it could be sent to user's phone as verification code.

While googling I found this npm library randomatic
https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomatic
which does what I require.

However, I am not sure how to use this in an `Ionic` app, particularly in a `Typescript` file. Based on the provided documentation this is what I tried.

**send-code.ts**

```
export class SendCodePage {

  var randomize = require('randomatic');

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private sms: SMS) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SendCodePage');
  }

  doSendCode() {
    let randomNum = randomize('0', 6);
    this.sms.send("1002001234", randomNum);
    this.navCtrl.push(ResetPasswordPage);
  }

}
```

As soon as I add the line `var randomize = require('randomatic');` my editor goes red. Not sure how to import it here or if it even can be used in an Ionic project or not.

Comment: `Math.random().toString().substr(-6)` would work as a simple vanilla JS solution, without relying on libraries etc.

Comment: That works. Thanks @Tyler

Comment: No problem. Admittedly, that solution is a bit cheeky, and I'm not sure that `Math.random()` is guaranteed to always return that many  characters. A friendlier (and much more efficient) solution might be something like `Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;`.